# How to make a generic function getById<T> that applies to members List<T> of class

Tags: c#, generics

Suppose there are a number of custom classes that have an `int Id` property.
There is another class which holds Lists of these custom classes. If we want to find an element of these classes by id, we might end up with duplicate code where only the class type changes, i.e:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public List<ClassA> As = new List<ClassA>();
    public List<ClassB> Bs = new List<ClassB>();
    
    public ClassA getClassAById(int id)
    {
        foreach (var classA in As)
        {
            if (classA.Id == id)
            {
                return classA;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public ClassB getClassBById(int id)
    {
        foreach (var classB in Bs)
        {
            if (classB.Id == id)
            {
                return classB;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to organise the code so as to avoid duplications and have one generic getElementById function that can be called with the respective class type and return an element of type T?

Comment: Basically you'd want the two classes to either have a common base class, or a common interface that defines the `Id` property. As asides, I'd strongly encourage you to a) follow .NET naming conventions; b) avoid exposing public fields; c) learn about LINQ - your methods could be as simple as `public ClassA GetClassAById(int id) => As.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);`

Answer (score 1):

You must have an `interface that has an Id property` and both classes A and B inherit from the interface.

```
    public interface baseInterface
    {
       int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class ClassA: baseInterface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClassB : baseInterface
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Then put the main `list of type baseInterface`:

```
    public class MainClass
    {
        public List<baseInterface> ABs = new List<baseInterface>();           

        public baseInterface getClassById(int id)
        {
            return ABs.Where(i=>i.Id==id).FirstOrDefault();

        }
   }
```

Comment: May I suggest the name of the interface not be "baseClass" as it's a bit confusing (it's not a class).  Perhaps "IHasId"?

Comment: How would the getClassById method be different if we wanted it to be called with a specific class derived from baseInterface and return the same type as the one it was called with? For example getClassById<ClassA> and return instance of ClassA.

Comment: @Tsaras `var r = mn.getClassAById(11);` You can specify the class type with this code: `r.GetType().Name`

Answer (score 1):

Using generics and an interface will reduce duplication.

```
public interface IHasId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : IHasId
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public List<ClassA> As = new List<ClassA>();
    public List<ClassB> Bs = new List<ClassB>();

    public T GetElementById<T>(List<T> list, int id) where T : IHasId
    {
        return list.FirstOrDefault(itm => itm.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use generics, yea

```
public class MainClass
{
    public List<ClassA> As = new List<ClassA>();
    public List<ClassB> Bs = new List<ClassB>();

    public T getElementById<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        var list = GetList<T>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            if (item.Id == id)
            {
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private List<T> GetList<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(ClassA))
        {
            return As as List<T>;
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ClassB))
        {
            return Bs as List<T>;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported type");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will not even compile.

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?)

Comment: yes, this code is just a simple example of using generics and type checking

Comment: and make sure to add using System.Collections.Generic at the beginning

Comment: How this code will get Id for `item.Id` with the only constraint being that `T` is class?)

Comment: getElementById , it is basically that ig

Comment: Yep, as expected - [does not compile](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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) =)